# How to trigger Lightbox Load once the user scroll to a Certain Div

Tags: jquery, scroll, lightbox, colorbox

So I am using colorbox to create a lightbox. Currently I have it so on the first page load, the user is shown a lightbox. A cookie is dropped, so the user don't see this lightbox for 15 more days. I would like to do it so the lightbox gets loaded only when a user scrolls to the div #cooler-nav.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        $.colorbox({width:"700px", inline:true, href:"#subscribepop"}); 
        }
});
</script>
```

P.S. I would like to keep the ability of the lightbox loading only once every 15 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).bind('scroll.showcolorbox', function() {
    if ($('body').scrollTop()+$(window).height() >  $('#cooler-nav').offset().top) {
        $.colorbox({...});
        $(window).unbind('scroll.showcolorbox');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Jasper has explained everything already... (except the unbind, which makes sure you only show the colorbox once)

Comment: I am able to run the code you share and get the Lightbox to load once the div #cooler-nav is reached. Unbinding works great as well. However I cannot figure out the cookies thing to work right.

What I would like to do is have the lightbox show only once every fifteen days.

Link to my code: http://pastebin.com/2VFKquAp

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var $special = $('#cooler-nav');
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($special.offset().top <= $('body').scrollTop()) {
            console.log('You have reached the `#special` element');
        } else {
            console.log('You aren\'t quite there yet.');
        }
    });
});
```

What you do is bind an event handler to the `scroll` event for the `window` object (or whatever object is being scrolled, i.e. has scroll-bars). In this event handler we get the top offset of the element you want to watch and see if the `window` has been scrolled to it's height.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wxeFP/ (watch your console to see the message change when you scroll past the `#cooler-nav` element)

If you want to run the code just as the `#cooler-nav` element comes into view you can add the `viewport`s height to the `body`s `scrollTop` value:

```
if ($special.offset().top <= ($('body').scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
```

Here is a demo for this: http://jsfiddle.net/wxeFP/1/

Comment: I am able to run the code Ori shared below and get the Lightbox to load once the div #cooler-nav is reached. Unbinding works great as well. However I cannot figure out the cookies thing to work right. What I would like to do is have the lightbox show only once every fifteen days. Link to my code: pastebin.com/2VFKquAp